# How to merge columns using mask

Tags: pandas, merge, mask

I am trying to merge two columns (Phone 1 and 2)

Here is my fake data:

```
import pandas as pd
employee = {'EmployeeID' : [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
         'LastName' : ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h'],
         'Name' : ['w', 'x', 'y', 'z', None, None, None, None],
         'phone1' : [1, 1, 2, 2, 4, 5, 6, 6],
         'phone2' : [None, None, 3, 3, None, None, 7, 7],
         'level_15' : [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1]}

df2 = pd.DataFrame(employee)
```

and I want the 'phone' column to be

```
'phone' : [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 9, 10]
```

In the beginning of my code, i split the names based on '/' and this code below creates a column with 0s and 1s which I used as mask to do other tasks through out my code.

```
df2 = (df2.set_index(cols)['name'].str.split('/',expand=True).stack().reset_index(name='Name'))

m = df2['level_15'].eq(0)
print (m)

#remove column level_15
df2 = df2.drop(['level_15'], axis=1)

#add last name for select first letter by condition, replace NaNs by forward fill
df2['last_name'] = df2['name'].str[:2].where(m).ffill()

df2['name'] = df2['name'].mask(m, df2['name'].str[2:])
```

I feel like there is a way to merge phone1 and phone2 using the 0s and 1s, but I can't figure out. Thank you.

Comment: Let me get this right. You want to take the value of alternating columns?

Comment: that is exactly right that mask has 0s and 1s alternatively. I will add one more column on my fake data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, start by filling in NaNs;

```
df2['phone2'] = df2.phone2.fillna(df2.phone1)

# Alternatively, based on your latest update
# df2['phone2'] = df2.phone2.mask(df2.phone2.eq(0)).fillna(df2.phone1)
```

You can just use `np.where` to merge columns on odd/even indices:

```
df2['phone'] = np.where(np.arange(len(df2)) % 2 == 0, df2.phone1, df2.phone2)
df2 = df2.drop(['phone1', 'phone2'], 1)

df2

   EmployeeID LastName  Name  phone
0           0        a     w      1
1           1        b     x      2
2           2        c     y      3
3           3        d     z      4
4           4        e  None      5
5           5        f  None      6
6           6        g  None      7
7           7        h  None      8
```

Or, with `Series.where`/`mask`:

```
df2['phone'] = df2.pop('phone1').where(
         np.arange(len(df2)) % 2 == 0, df2.pop('phone2')
)
```

Or,

```
df2['phone'] = df2.pop('phone1').mask(
         np.arange(len(df2)) % 2 != 0, df2.pop('phone2)
)
```

```
df2

   EmployeeID LastName  Name  phone
0           0        a     w      1
1           1        b     x      2
2           2        c     y      3
3           3        d     z      4
4           4        e  None      5
5           5        f  None      6
6           6        g  None      7
7           7        h  None      8
```

Comment: can you please briefly explain what % 2 == 0 do?

Comment: @YunTaeHwang Even indices -> phone 1, odd indices -> phone2

Comment: oh.. there is some excpetions... shoot let me modify my fake data one more time....sorry

Comment: @YunTaeHwang Add this line at the top: `df2['phone2'] = df2.phone2.fillna(df2.phone1)` and then call the code as normal.

Comment: Now you wiill see, I found some people who had a partner without phone2

Comment: @YunTaeHwang Add this line at the start: `df2['phone2'] = df2.phone2.mask(df2.phone2.eq(0)).fillna(df2.phone1)`

Comment: It is really similar to what I want, but is there any way to do this without filling the no values in phone2? because if I fill it I get the value in phone1 for people who doesn't have a phone number. 

Its like phone 1 is for people with the mask 0 and phone 2s for the ones with the mask 1

and I really appreciate for your help :)